# What sort of information is accessible from a user's Google account using OAuth2.0?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

If you get a user to log in to your website using Google's authentication, then what information can you get about them? Specifically, can you get their Ad Preferences that Google collects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any Google API that reveals the Ad Preferences of a user. You can see your own Ad Preferences with the Ad Preference Manager, but that doesn't have an API to allow authorized people see someone else's preferences.